# JavaScript - Get dates in between two dates from weekdays

Tags: javascript

I receive a start and end date and I want to extract all the dates that are between these two dates, but only on specified weekdays.

I wrote a small code that calculate the dates for "Tuesday, Wednesday and Friday" between the dates:

```
start_date = "2019-12-31"
end_date = "2020-01-31"
```

it works ok but the problem is that it start to calculate from 'Tuesday 07-01-2020' and I want to start to get the date from 'Tuesday 31-12-2019'. The code is as follows:

```
 function nextWeekdayDate(date, day_in_week) {
    var ret = new Date(date || new Date());
    ret.setDate(ret.getDate() + (day_in_week - 1 - ret.getDay() + 7) % 7 + 1);
    return ret;
}

var delivery_dates = []

var day_num = { "Mon": 1, "Tue": 2, "Wed": 3, "Thu": 4, "Fri": 5 };
var days_of_week = ["Tue", "Wed", "Fri"];

start_date = new Date('2019-12-31');
end_date = new Date('2020-01-31');

var new_dates = []
 while (start_date < end_date) {
  for (var i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
    start_date = nextWeekdayDate(start_date, day_num[days_of_week[i]]);
    delivery_dates.push(start_date)
  }
}
console.log(delivery_dates);
```

Any idea what is wrong with my code? here is a jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/mpe49hun/8/

Comment: `ret.setDate(ret.getDate() + ((day_in_week - 1 - ret.getDay() + 7) % 7 + 1) % 7);` seems to fix it (the extra %7) ... or better `ret.setDate(ret.getDate() + ((day_in_week - 1 - ret.getDay() + 7) + 1) % 7);` - there's probably even better way to shuffle the values to get more succinct code

Comment: @JaromandaX Thank you very much. It indeed fixes the problem. Could kindly explain why? Also can you post your comment as an anwser and I will accept it as the solution.

Comment: `ret.setDate(ret.getDate() + ((7 + day_in_week - ret.getDay())) % 7);` does it too

Comment: explanation ... you add 7 days on the first call to your function ... rather than 0, since start_date is a tuesday

Comment: One thing though ... if the start date is `25 dec 2019` ... would you expect the 25th and 27th to be included? they won't be

Comment: If you would expect the above ... https://jsfiddle.net/h9g1e72m/ - far simpler code, yeah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the first date is a Tuesday, the function

```
function nextWeekdayDate(date, day_in_week) {
    var ret = new Date(date || new Date());
    ret.setDate(ret.getDate() + (day_in_week - 1 - ret.getDay() + 7) % 7 + 1);
    return ret;
}
```

adds seven days to `ret` when it should be zero

changing the "maths" to `ret.setDate(ret.getDate() + ((7 + day_in_week - ret.getDay())) % 7);` will fix this

```js
function nextWeekdayDate(date, day_in_week) {
  var ret = new Date(date || new Date());
  ret.setDate(ret.getDate() + ((7 + day_in_week - ret.getDay())) % 7);
  return ret;
}
var delivery_dates = []

var day_num = {
  "Mon": 1,
  "Tue": 2,
  "Wed": 3,
  "Thu": 4,
  "Fri": 5
};
var days_of_week = ["Tue", "Wed", "Fri"];

start_date = new Date('2019-12-31');
end_date = new Date('2020-01-31');

var new_dates = []
while (start_date < end_date) {
  for (var i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
    start_date = nextWeekdayDate(start_date, day_num[days_of_week[i]]);
    delivery_dates.push(start_date)
  }
}
console.log(delivery_dates);
```

---

However, given a start date of 2019-12-25, for example, the wednesday 25/12 and friday 27/12 wont' be included in the output - if it should be included, then the following code is probably what you want

```js
var delivery_dates = []

var day_num = { "Mon": 1, "Tue": 2, "Wed": 3, "Thu": 4, "Fri": 5 };
var days_of_week = ["Tue", "Wed", "Fri"];
var includedDays = days_of_week.map(d => day_num[d]);


start_date = new Date('2019-12-25');
end_date = new Date('2020-01-31');

while (start_date <= end_date) {
    if (includedDays.includes(start_date.getDay())) {
        delivery_dates.push(new Date(start_date));
    }
    start_date.setDate(start_date.getDate() + 1);
}
console.log(delivery_dates)
```